# Jest __mocks__ folder with multiple "projects" configurations

Tags: jestjs

Project has a single **node_moudules** in root dir. Jest config has separate **projects** settings for *backend* and *frontend* subfolders.

I want to mock node modules using the `__mocks__` folder.  It works if I put `__mocks__` inside "*backend/src*" but how can I have a single `__mocks__` folder for both frontend and backend?

**jest.config:**

```
export default {
  projects: [
    {
      displayName: 'Backend',
      rootDir: './backend',
      roots: ['<rootDir>/src'],
    },
  ],
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had to add a second entry to *roots*:

```
roots: ['<rootDir>/src', '<rootDir>/../__mocks__']
```